# Linker error when launching tests after a Project Clean with cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods, xctest

I've recently adopted cocoapods in my project, and everything seems to work fine except for a small annoying thing.

Before cocoapods, hitting cmd+u would have compiled my entire project and run tests; after adding cocoapods if I hit cmd+u after a project clean (Product->clean or shift+cmd+k) I receive a linker error, precisely:

```
//{Path_To_My_app} is the path to my app's folder and {MyAppName} is my app's name

ld: file not found: /Users/my_name/{Path_To_My_app}/Build/Products/Debug-   iphonesimulator/{MyAppName}.app/{MyAppName}
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

to make it work I have to build it first and than hit cmd+u.
To be precise  I can't remember if this was so before, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't...I can't seem to understand why this happens, and why hitting "cmd+u" is not building the project and than running the tests.

**EDIT**

I have specified in my podfile to add some pods just to my test target, so it is like:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

pod 'SVProgressHUD', :head
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.0.7'
pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 3.0.2'


target "MyTestTarget" do
pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.2.4'
end
```